# How to get access to the Holographic Space from a 2D windows universal app?

Tags: uwp, msdn, hololens

I have a windows universal app I would like to place in a HolographicSpace such that I can have the 2D View but I can also interact with 3d models at the same time which will be coming alive from my 2D view. I would like to know which is the best way to do so ? I saw the Holograms application in the hololens example apps but I don't know how do you load the 2D view and call the 3D widgets as models from the 2D View.

Answer (score 2):

Your application cannot mix 2D and 3D mode *at the same time*.

You can have a 2D window in the shell Holographic Space but when you want to see a 3D model, you need to switch your app in 3D mode which takes over the entire Holographic space. from there, you could switch back to 2D mode.

It's a bit unclear on how to achieve this as it's not really well documented, but I recommend you start on the [hololens documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/documentation) pages and go from there.

Comment: Alex thanks, I still think there should be a way to do it since Holograms the example app loads a 3D widget after clicking on a 2D Window. The hololens documentation is heavy unity focused.

Comment: Like many other functions, the Holograms app is using private APIs that are not available to regular developers.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

As above already said, a mix will not be possible. But you can create a new corewindow in your app that has a dispatcher. with it you can switch to it. the new window should be similiar to the provided holographicapp from microsoft.

This is how i switch back to my 2D app:

```
this.Dispatcher.TryRunIdleAsync(async p =>
        {
            //Switch to the other window
            await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(parentWindowId);
        });
```

I hope i could help you to get an idea how it works. But like already said above, the documentation is a great place to get started.